# Delete/Modify an element in a struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a program that stores a "friends" info into a struct array and writes it to a file. No problem there. But how would I be able to modify and/or delete a specific element in that struct array? Did some reading and it says I can't, unless I was to shift it all over by one after deleting in.

So I'm assuming I need to read it in, then remove it, and shift all other elements over by one and write it again...but how would I do this? Tried to include only the necessary code I have so far.

For modifying it, I would guess I'd read it in, then ask for the specific element # I want to change, then set all the values in that element to null, then allow the user to input new info? How would this code look?

```
struct FriendList
{
    char screenname[32];
    char country[32];
    char city[32];
    char interests[32];
    short age;

};

int main()
{
FriendList friends[num_friends];
const int num_friends = 2;

// Gets user input and puts it into struct array and writes to file

case 3:
        {   // Getting info and putting in struct elements
                for (index = 0; index < num_friends; index++)
                {
                // Create Friend Records
                cout << "Enter Screename " << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(friends[index].screenname, 32);
                cout << "Country: " << endl;
                cin >> friends[index].country;
                cout << "City: " << endl;
                cin >> friends[index].city;
                cout << "Age: " << endl;
                cin >> friends[index].age;

                }
                counting += index;

                fstream infile;
                infile.open("friends.dat", ios::out | ios::binary |ios::app);
                if(infile.fail())
                { cout << "File not found!\n\t";
                // exit
                }

                    // Writing struct to file
                infile.write((char*)&friends, sizeof(friends));

                infile.close();

            break;
        }

// Delete a friend ???
    case 5:
        {   // Reading in file contents into struct friends
                        // Then????
            fstream outfile;
            outfile.open("friends.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
            outfile.read((char*)&friends, sizeof(friends));

            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It can modify member of the struct. But you don't clear memory at the first, you will see garages in `friends.dat`.
in upper of main, you have better to add `memset()`.

```
memset(&friends, 0, sizeof(friends));
```

And you use ios::app . I guess that `friends` is full-set datas. Then, you should remove ios::app ?

BTW, in late about C++, most of c++er don't use binary file for like this case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change is relatively easy - just read the right entry, update it in memory and write back. In order to delete I suggest the following:

1. Read all the entries after the one u need to delete
2. Write those entries in the offset of the deleted entries
3. Truncate the fuile to the new length

This is the trivial approach

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want either a std::deque or a std::vector depending on usage.

If you are deleting items infrequently, then use the std::vector instead of a fixed array:

```
std::vector<FriendList> friends;
```

to add new friends:

```
friends.push_back(newFriend);
```

accessing a friend by index is the same as accessing an array:

```
friends[index]
```

to delete an entry in the vector, use erase() (not remove()!):

```
friends.erase(friends.begin() + index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method delete, which pulls the friend after the one you want to delete, moves the info to the current struct, and continues until there are no more friends.